# Close vote queue audit showing question before edit

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

I have came across audit questions in the Close vote queue several times that had wrong tags initially, which have been removed by an edit, but the audit was still showing the questions with the wrong tag.

I am usually filtering tags when reviewing questions in this queue and hence it is a bit misleading when questions come up that have nothing to do with those tags. As an example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16995143) is a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) question, that initially had the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag as well, but has nothing to do with [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift). I am not sure if the question comes up in the form of an audit as well to other people, so [here](https://image.prntscr.com/image/B7ayN8nqQ1O6s676-OmAyw.png) is a screenshot of the audit. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513155/voice-detection-virtual-assistant-in-python) is the question itself, in its closed form as *too broad*.

I was just wondering if this is a bug in the audit system or expected behaviour?  I am not sure if these questions come up on purpose to make the audit easier to spot or if it is just a bug that all audit questions come in their original, unedited form and in such cases they end up shown in to people even when they use filtered tags.

Comment: If you are filtering on a specific tag and you get a weird one that is probably the system adding the tag to it because it is an audit.  I love getting Haskell questions tagged as C++.

Comment: Taking a closer look to this particular question, you are right, the tags weren't edited at all. I only had the feeling that it might no be intentional, because there actually were some audit questions, were the wrong tag was removed in an edit. Thanks for the info anyways!

Comment: This is almost certainly the easiest way to spot an audit when filtering on a tag. I filter on `VB.NET` and sometimes get a completely random question tagged as it. I check it out thinking _why have they used that tag?_ and often find it hasn't got the tag at all and that it's just an audit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The audit system is adding the tag to the question (just when viewed from the queue) so that you can't tell that the post is an audit purely by looking at the tags and seeing that none of them are a tag you're filtering on.

Comment: To some extent it makes sense, but on the other hand I can almost immediately tell that it is an audit because of the totally irrelevant tag. And even if I couldn't tell, I usually open the question itself on a  new tag to try to remove the irrelevant tag and then I immediately see that it has been closed already. However, I guess by opening the question itself the audit gets the expected results, since if I wasn't paying attention to the review, I wouldn't bother editing the tags.

Comment: @DávidPásztor That you're paying enough attention to tell that the question has nothing to do with those tags means the audit *is doing it job* and ensuring that you're actually looking at the question closely enough to see its topic.  The audits are basically there to stop people from mashing one of the review buttons without even reading any of the question.  Since you noticed it's an audit, you weren't doing that.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Gotta love 'em `[wordpress][c++]` ones...

Comment: This can be very annoying, and frequently incorrect. For example, it sometimes marks a [c] question as [c++] as well, which can very easily make the question too broad or unclear.

Comment: Wait, so it adds a wrong tag to a known good question and if I press comment to ask for explanation or try to edit out the wrong edit I will be banned?